# Where can I find the security enhancement of solc compiler?

Tags: security, solc

I came from [this link](https://underhanded.soliditylang.org/), and quote

> It is highly encouraged to use Solidity v0.7.0 or newer. If you want to use a version of the 0.6 series, please make sure to not make use of flaws that have been fixed in 0.7. Don't use versions older than 0.6

And looks like solc fixes a lot of security bugs in each release, and I want to figure out what security issue was fixed at compiler level.

I found this [release notes](https://blog.soliditylang.org/category/releases/) page, and I tried to open a few of them but there's nothing about security.

How can I get a the list of security enhancement in each release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [the documentation on Security](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/bugs.html#list-of-known-bugs) about all known bugs. It is a list of bugs from 0.3.0 and up to today formatted in JSON with the information on when the bug was introduced, whether it has been fixed, when it has been fixed, what version of Solidity it impacts.